# adding buttons after appending firstChild

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I want to add two more buttons to edit and delete the appended `firstChild` value.

How do I do that?

```
function writeParagraph() {
    var comment = prompt("Type content for new paragraph here", "");
    var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    newParagraph.textContent = comment;
    document.getElementById("updateDiv").appendChild(newParagraph);
}
function deleteParagraph() {
var items = document.querySelectorAll("#updateDiv p");
if (items.length) {
var child = items[0];
child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div align="center"> <button onclick="store();prompter();">Click Me and type!</button>    </div>
<div align="center"> <button onclick="undo()">Undo</button></div>
<div align="center"> <button onclick="prompter2()">Set Allign</button></div>
<div align="center"> <button id="a" onclick="writepara()">Click for a new     paragraph</button></div>
<div align="center"> <button id="b" onclick="deleteParagraph()">Click to delete the new paragraph</button></div>
<div id='updateDiv' align="center"> </div>
```

Comment: to explain more this function is linked to a onclick event which takes user input from prompt and creates a new para... now i wat to delete/edit the para... some codes and guidelines will highly appreciated

Comment: So, what code have you tried for inserting the buttons?  You copied my `delegeParagraph()` code from my answer.  You know how to insert a paragraph.  It seems like you ought to write your own code to insert the buttons and then ask more specific questions when you get stuck.

Comment: @jfriend00 I dont even know how add buttons using appendChild or nodes :(... Thats where im stuck... And yes that deletePragraph function was given by you.. And thank you very much for that! :)

Comment: `var b = document.createElement("button");`  Then set properties on the button to set it text and its click handler and then insert it with `.appendChild(b)` just like you did for the paragraph.  You can find examples on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete would be:

```
function deleteParagraph() {
     var items = document.querySelectorAll("#updateDiv p");
     if (items.length) {
         var child = items[0];
         child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
     }
}
```

Edit would be:

```
function changeParagraph(newHTML) {
     var items = document.querySelectorAll("#updateDiv p");
     if (items.length) {
         var child = items[0];
         child.innerHTML = newHTML;
     }
}
```

You will have to separately prompt from whatever text you want to pass to `changeParagraph()`.

Comment: thanks @jfriend00
however... how to add them in a button and appear at the same time when the firstChild is being appended? for example I typed "Hello World" and i want edit n delete button with these functions to appear on the side.. please help

Comment: @envym6 - What part do you not know how to do?  You obviously know how to create a paragraph element and add it.  You can create a button element the same way.  I don't know where you want the buttons or how you want them formatted so that part is up to you.  Perhaps you should show the BEFORE and AFTER HTML so we know exactly what you're trying to create.  And, please clarify using the edit link in your original post not in comments.  After editing your original post, add a comment to say what you modified.

Comment: I want these deleteParagraph() and changeParagraph() functions to be added on a onclick event inside a button. and them buttons should appear after i have clicked "Click for a new paragraph"
@jfriend00